# How to - from UML diagrams to Class diagrams using design patterns

Tags: design-patterns, uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

I'm working with a friend on a university project which involves a software product to manage a library (most of all loans and purchase of books).
We have yet produced a lot of documents and a lot of diagrams: Use Case diagrams, Sequence diagrams and Activity diagrams, Architecture diagrams.

Now, starting from the previous diagrams, we have to efficiently produce Class diagrams using design patterns: how to proceed?

Comment: Umm...carefully? :P  Not sure what the question is.  (I will say, though, that if part of your requirements is "uses design patterns", you're doing it wrong.)

Comment: @cHao Well, we don't know how to proceed. What are we doing wrong?

Comment: "How to proceed" is an extremely vague thing to ask about.   As for what you're doing wrong, if you're referring to my comment, it sounds like you're trying too hard to use design patterns by any means necessary, rather than letting the project tell you whether/where they would fit well.

Comment: @cHao I think I get your point, but it's the first time we work on something like that.
As for the question: 1) we don't know how to correctly extrapolate specific design patterns from our previous diagrams (especially sequence diagrams); 2) how to translate (map) these diagrams into Class diagrams.

Comment: Theoretical question that belongs on programmers.SE

Comment: This http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/classDiagram.htm#HowTo may be useful. BTW: if your project involves delivering a software product then perhaps it is also a time to create the deliverable software product (do some coding, e.g. some prototype to throw away). It seems that you have already done the thinking and documentation and high-level talking. Even more high-level talking will not push you further if you can't do the low-level work

Answer (score 0):

From what you write it looks like what you are looking for is to create a (or a couple) of domain models. A domain model captures the concepts and properties from the business domain.

Normally you can identify the concepts in the business domain easily from your use cases, e.g. if you would have a use case called **Register for Subscription**, it wouldn't surprise me that you will find a domain object called **Subscription**.

I've written a couple of posts earlier that might help you shape your domain models and use cases as well:

- [Modeling domain models in UML](http://sanderhoogendoorn.com/blog/index.php/modeling-your-domain-models-in-uml/)
- [Describing (smart) use cases in Enterprise Architect, part I](http://sanderhoogendoorn.com/blog/index.php/describing-smart-use-cases-using-enterprise-architect-8-part-itemplates-and-validations/)
- [Describing (smart) use cases in Enterprise Architect, part II](http://sanderhoogendoorn.com/blog/index.php/describing-smart-use-cases-using-enterprise-architect-8-part-ii-use-case-scenarios-and-structured-specifications/)

Basically, UML will not tell you how to do this, UML is a specification, you might consider it a toolbox. What you build with it, is up to you.

Comment: Well, actually we already produced domain models using both Use Case diagrams and Class diagrams. Now we have to proceed to the design phase, in which we must produce other artificats such as the Class Diagrams (containing all the actual class that will be implemented)

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It looks like you're going to try to create class diagrams (and than likely more sequence diagrams) that display your architecture. Now unless you are actually documenting your architecture, I wouldn't do that. The value is limited, and the amount of work is considerate. Try to figure out what the goals are for trying to achieve these design class diagrams.

Comment: Well, we're actually documenting our system architecture from many point of views. Indeed, we already produced Sequence and Activity diagrams at the "design level".

Comment: What we've done in quite a few projects is to create sequence diagrams for the patterns that you use repetitively. That helps. But to model each and every class in your architecture, and probably also your frameworks, I wouldn't do that. It is a lot of work, and the value is limited, as you will need to re-model every time something changes. I would stick to an overview, and not an exact model.

Comment: Sure, we don't model each and every class of our architecture, but only the relevant ones identified from an analysis on requirements and a ranking on use cases. So, at the moment, we have 6 relevant use cases, traduced into 6 Sequence and Activity diagrams. Now, we take 2 from the 6 and proceed further in the design.

Answer (score 0):

Use cases show the user requirements of the system.  Sequence diagrams (depending on the detail) either show how objects interact or how subsystems interact.  If your sequence diagrams are at a higher level of abstraction, then you have to come up with your classes.  I suggest having an object blitz in which you list all the nouns that you can think of... book, library, librarian, catalogue, borrower, date, book location, fine, etc.  Make sure that all your requirements are met by your classes and the associations between the classes.  Discard any classes that don't have responsibilities after your analysis.  Go through all your sequence diagrams and see if you can assign classes to the lifelines.  If not, you may be missing a class.  Eventually, all scenarios must be played out by classes in your class diagram.